# Is this "homework kind" question off topic?

Tags: discussion, flags

I can't decide whether should I flag this question: [In-order Traversal for custom B-tree Ocaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55071968/in-order-traversal-for-custom-b-tree-ocaml). It strongly looks like a kind of "do my homework" post which I suspect isn't what we want to have on SO.

However, I couldn't find matching case in report menu. What do you think?

Comment: Homework questions are not off-topic per se, but the consensus is that we expect to see a decent honest attempt at a solution within the poster's question, and then the OP should use of this attempt to help craft a specific and high-quality question. Please have a look at [How do I ask and answer Homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852). I usually tell the OP that this information is valid whether or not the question is for homework or home work (self-study).

Comment: I personally would use the off-topic, while as mentioned by the hovercraft full of eels it's not off-topic as such, it fits the best in my opinion

Comment: It doesn't matter, "I want this code" is not a question.  You can close it with about everything.

Comment: @Epodax but off-topic has its own branches: general computing hw and sw, server/networking, recommend book or other resource, debugging, non reproducible, blantantly off-topic and other stack exchange case. Which one would you use?